# Regex Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

i don't how replace this text into this:

```
ab fg\r fsd&
```

into this:

```
a
b

f
g
\r

f
s
d
&
```

*And Viceversa:*

```
r
f

f
f
```

into this:

```
rf ff
```

Can u help me, please?

Comment: Is it intentional that there's no newline between `\ ` and `r`? What exactly is the rule? Are there spaces on the "empty" lines?

Comment: yes..the empty lines ARE spaces, not empty lines. The \r is right, there isn't newline

Answer (score 1):

To go from one line to many:

- Find: `(.)` - Find any single character and capture it for reference
  in the replace
- Replace: `\1\r\n` - put the first capture then add a
  carrage return and a new line.

Assuming there is a space on the empty line you can go back by switching from Regex to Extended and using:

- Find: `\r\n` - find the end of a line
- Replace - leave it blank.

Comment: \r\n --> leave blank it gives me all the letters without regard to neighboring spaces.

Comment: @user143822 As Scott already said, it works if all "empty" lines contain a space (they will if you previously used the described first regex replacement for splitting). However, if empty lines are indeed _empty_ then there is no space to respect when replacing all occurrences of `\r\n` with an empty string.